# How to send a confirmation code to a email using JavaMailSender in Spring Boot (sts 4)?

Tags: java, html, ajax, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I'm very new to coding, and I would like to seek some advices from the community.
I want to construct a basic format of sending a random code to a designated email address; in this case, I'm trying to send it to a "Naver" email address, but when I click the "send code", the browser doesn't respond accordingly.

Here's my MailConfig class:

```java
package com.example.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;

@Configuration
public class MailConfig {

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailService() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        javaMailSender.setHost("smtp.naver.com"); 
        javaMailSender.setUsername("네이버 아이디"); 
        javaMailSender.setPassword("네이버 비밀번호"); 

        javaMailSender.setPort(465); 

        javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(getMailProperties()); 

        return javaMailSender;
    }
    
    private Properties getMailProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp"); 
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
        properties.setProperty("mail.debug", "true"); 
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust","smtp.naver.com"); 
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable","true"); 
        return properties;
    }
}
```

MailServiceInter interface:

```java
package com.example.service;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;



import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import jakarta.mail.MessagingException;
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

@Service
public interface MailServiceInter {
    
    MimeMessage createMessage(String to) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException;
    
    String createKey();
    
    String sendSimpleMessage(String to) throws Exception;

}
```

RegisterMail class:

```java
package com.example.service;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Random;



import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import jakarta.mail.MessagingException;
import jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage.RecipientType;

@Service
public class RegisterMail implements MailServiceInter {

    @Autowired
    JavaMailSender emailsender; 

    private String ePw; // 인증번호

    
    @Override
    public MimeMessage createMessage(String to) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
//      System.out.println("Recipient : " + to);
//      System.out.println("Confirm Code : " + ePw);
        
        MimeMessage message = emailsender.createMimeMessage();

        message.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO, to);// 보내는 대상
        message.setSubject("GoodJob 회원가입 이메일 인증");

        String msgg = "";
        msgg += "<div style='margin:100px;'>";
        msgg += "<h1> 안녕하세요</h1>";
        msgg += "<h1> 통합 취업 정보 포탈 GoodJob 입니다</h1>";
        msgg += "<br>";
        msgg += "<p>아래 코드를 회원가입 창으로 돌아가 입력해주세요<p>";
        msgg += "<br>";
        msgg += "<p>항상 당신의 꿈을 응원합니다. 감사합니다!<p>";
        msgg += "<br>";
        msgg += "<div align='center' style='border:1px solid black; font-family:verdana';>";
        msgg += "<h3 style='color:blue;'>회원가입 인증 코드입니다.</h3>";
        msgg += "<div style='font-size:130%'>";
        msgg += "CODE : <strong>";
        msgg += ePw + "</strong><div><br/> "; 
        msgg += "</div>";
        message.setText(msgg, "utf-8", "html");
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("randomEmail@naver.com", "GoodJob_Admin"));

        return message;
    }

    
    @Override
    public String createKey() {
        StringBuffer key = new StringBuffer();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { 
            int index = rnd.nextInt(3); 

            switch (index) {
            case 0:
                key.append((char) ((int) (rnd.nextInt(26)) + 97));
                // a~z (ex. 1+97=98 => (char)98 = 'b')
                break;
            case 1:
                key.append((char) ((int) (rnd.nextInt(26)) + 65));
                // A~Z
                break;
            case 2:
                key.append((rnd.nextInt(10)));
                // 0~9
                break;
            }
        }

        return key.toString();
    }

    
    @Override
    public String sendSimpleMessage(String to) throws Exception {

        ePw = createKey(); 

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MimeMessage message = createMessage(to); 
        try {// 예외처리
            emailsender.send(message);
        } catch (MailException es) {
            es.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }


        return ePw; 
    }
}
```

my AccountController:

```
package com.example.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.example.service.RegisterMail;




@Controller
public class AccountController {
    
    @Autowired
    RegisterMail registerMail;
    
    @PostMapping("/login/mailConfirm")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> mailConfirm(@RequestParam("email") String email) {
        try {
            String code = registerMail.sendSimpleMessage(email);
            System.out.println("인증코드 : " + code);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(code, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log the exception details here and return an appropriate error message
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Error sending email", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

and lastly my html file:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Email Verification</title>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-group last mb-4 email_input">
        <label for="memail" id="mailTxt">이메일을 입력해주세요</label> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="memail" id="memail">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" id="checkEmail">인증번호</button>

    <div class="form-group last mb-4 check_input">
        <label for="memailconfirm" id="memailconfirmTxt">인증번호를 입력해주세요</label> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="memailconfirm">
    </div>

    <script>
    
    
    
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $memail = $('#memail');
            var $memailconfirm = $('#memailconfirm');
            var $memailconfirmTxt = $('#memailconfirmTxt');
            var emconfirmchk = false; 

            $('#checkEmail').click(function() {
                var email = $memail.val();
                if(email) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/login/mailConfirm", 
                    dataType: "text",
                    timeout: 30000,
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader(csrfHeader, csrfToken);
                    },
                    data: {
                        "email": $memail.val()
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert("해당 이메일로 인증번호 발송이 완료되었습니다. \n 확인부탁드립니다.");
                        console.log("data : " + data);
                        chkEmailConfirm(data, $memailconfirm, $memailconfirmTxt);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error("Error occurred: " + status + "\nError: " + error);
                        alert("Failed to send the email. Please try again.");
                    }
                });
                
                }else {
                    alert("Please enter an email address.");
                }
            });

            function chkEmailConfirm(data, $memailconfirm, $memailconfirmTxt) {
                $memailconfirm.on("keyup", function() {
                    if (data != $memailconfirm.val()) {
                        emconfirmchk = false;
                        $memailconfirmTxt.html("<span id='emconfirmchk'>인증번호가 잘못되었습니다</span>");
                        $("#emconfirmchk").css({
                            "color": "#FA3E3E",
                            "font-weight": "bold",
                            "font-size": "10px"
                        });
                    } else {
                        emconfirmchk = true;
                        $memailconfirmTxt.html("<span id='emconfirmchk'>인증번호 확인 완료</span>");
                        $("#emconfirmchk").css({
                            "color": "#0D6EFD",
                            "font-weight": "bold",
                            "font-size": "10px"
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is the structure of my full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP2EK.png)

I think the problem resides in the ajax method in my html file; the browser is able to respond to the "$('#checkEmail').click(function()" because when I click the send button without typing any email address, it shows me the alert window with the message "Failed to send the email. Please try again.".

There is no other error message on the console nor on the Chrome browser.

Comment: If you're seeing the "Failed to send..." alert then your code should have logged  something on the console. What?

Comment: Hi, the only alert message I could get on the browser is "Please enter an email address."

Comment: Can you explain what actually happens when the browser doesn't "respond accordingly"? Any error message? You should be testing your API in an application like Postman or Insomnia before using it directly in a website. It'll make the process mush easier :)